# How do i know a table size and row counts for each month, for the past six months?

Tags: sql-server

Using sql server can i get the row count and size of the table as well as the database size for the past six months?

Comment: If you have datetime as a column and not modified, you can get the row count. Post your table definition.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are tracking tables, table size can not be known. To get current size:

```
sp_spaceused 'TableName'
```

To get row count:

```
Select count(*) from 'TableName'
```

To get row count with a timestamp field:

```
    Select
          DATEPART(YEAR, 'timestamp_field') AS 'Year',
          DATEPART(MONTH, 'timestamp_field') AS 'Month',
          DATEPART(DAY, 'timestamp_field') AS 'Day',
          COUNT(*) AS Check

    from
         'TableName'
    group by
         DATEPART(DAY, 'timestamp_field'),
          DATEPART(MONTH, 'timestamp_field'),
          DATEPART(YEAR, 'timestamp_field')  
ORDER BY  'Year',  
          'Month',  
          'Day'
```

Database growth:

```
SELECT
[database_name] AS DB,
DATEPART(day,[backup_start_date]) AS Day,
DATEPART(month,[backup_start_date]) AS Month,
DATEPART(year,[backup_start_date]) AS Year,
AVG([backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Backup Size MB",
AVG([compressed_backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Compressed Backup Size MB",
AVG([backup_size]/[compressed_backup_size]) AS "Compression Ratio"
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
WHERE [database_name] = N'AdventureWorks'
AND [type] = 'D'
GROUP BY [database_name],DATEPART(m,[backup_start_date]),DATEPART(d,[backup_start_date]),DATEPART(y,[backup_start_date]),backup_start_date;
```

[for database size details. Check this link](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/trending-database-growth-from-backups/)
[Create table size tracking report](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2794/report-to-capture-table-growth-statistics-for-sql-server/)

Comment: >>>updated the code<<< The code that calculates backup size still adds all the years under the same month

Answer (score 2):

If you did not set up `Data Collector` or any custom job that saves periodically database/table sizes you cannot get these sizes in the past

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in mechanism for SQL to track table or database growth over time. Lots of 3rd-party monitoring tools can do this.

Where I work we have custom daily SQL jobs that query the database sizes (and lots of other info) on all our servers and store it in a `DBAInfo` database so we can query it later if necessary.

If your table has a "created_date" column or something equivalent, then you can use that to get some results for your table:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_date) as yr, MONTH(created_date) as mth, 
       COUNT(*) as rws
FROM mytable
GROUP BY YEAR(created_date), MONTH(created_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(created_date), MONTH(created_date)
```

(**WARNING**: this query will run for a very long time on a good-sized table.)

To estimate table size growth per month, just use the above row counts by month, and divide by the total table size, which you can get from `sp_spaceused 'TableName'`.

If you want the *actual* row sizes as stored in your table, that's much more difficult, you'd have to do some weird stuff with `DATALENGTH()`, see [this post for some ideas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table).

**EDIT**: To use the output of `sp_spaceused`, set up a temp table, then parse the string:

```
create table #tbl(
  name nvarchar(128),
  rows varchar(50),
  reserved varchar(50),
  data varchar(50),
  index_size varchar(50),
  unused varchar(50))

insert into #tbl exec sp_spaceused 'dbo.AccountLogons'

select name, rows,
    convert(int, substring(reserved, 1, len(reserved)-3)) as reserved_kb,
    convert(int, substring(data, 1, len(data)-3)) as data_kb,
    convert(int, substring(index_size, 1, len(index_size)-3)) as index_kb,
    convert(int, substring(unused, 1, len(unused)-3)) as free_kb
 from #tbl

drop table #tbl
```